# Founding a values in parsed multidimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I've got this data serialized by JSON to string:

```
var json = '[{"data":{"id":2,"gid":3,"name":"Travis","surname":"Stewart","skin":0}},{"data":{"id":3,"gid":3,"name":"Ziutek","surname":"Stewart","skin":0}}]';
```

And now im going to parse this back to object, like:

```
var charData = JSON.parse(json);
```

How can i get data from this for each datas?

```
for(var char in charData.data) {
console.log(char.id);
}
```

This wasn't work... Any other solutions?

Comment: That console log back me an errors:
`Error: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

Comment: at top-level you have an array, so `charData.data` is wrong. You have to loop over each array item, and access the item `data` property ; this is not what you've done

Comment: paste your json into an inline json beautifer, such as http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/, click on "viewer" at the top left, and see your json in a tree representation

Comment: @Pierre https://iv.pl/images/d01356524b8a27df9f82d9bbea968ac7.th.png - that what i've got in jsonviewer.

Comment: so you see you have to do something with the array... update your loop to handle that

Answer (score 1):

you have more then one `Data` object , so you need to do a forOf To your `chardata` not to `charData.data` :

```
for(var char in charData) {
console.log(charData[char].data.id);
console.log(charData[char].data.name);
 ....
}
```

Comment: Your code put me an error in console like:
`Error: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

Comment: try to log only console.log(char); and tell me what you got

Comment: That `for(var char in charData) {
console.log(char);
}` put me in console this `> "0"
> "1"`

Comment: a screenshot please

Comment: then try  : `console.log(charData[char]);`

Comment: `Object { data: Object { id: 2, gid: 3, name: "Travis", surname: "Stewart", skin: 0 } }
Object { data: Object { id: 3, gid: 3, name: "Ziutek", surname: "Stewart", skin: 0 } }`

Answer (score 1):

Okay. Got it! Here's the code how can i get this:

```
var json = '[{"data":{"id":2,"gid":3,"name":"Travis","surname":"Stewart","skin":0}},{"data":{"id":3,"gid":3,"name":"Ziutek","surname":"Stewart","skin":0}}]';
var charData = JSON.parse(json);

for(var char in charData) {
console.log(charData[char].data.name);
}
```

Thanks a lot for all! :) SOLVED.